# How many verses are there in extant Vishnu Purana?

Tags: vishnu-purana

According to tradition, Vishnu Purana has 23,000 verses. How many verses exist in the extant Vishnu Purana?

Comment: Only 6500 verses are present in Shri Vishnu Purana. Remaining are in the Vishnudharmottara Purana.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this Critical Edition](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/3_purana/vipce_pu.htm) available on the [GRETIL](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil.html) website:

> Visnu-Purana 
>   Based on: The Critical Edition of the Viṣṇupurāṇam, 
>   Critically Edited by M. M. Pathak, Vadodara, Oriental Institute 1997-1999.

...the total # of verses is about **5276**.

And if you go by the [Bombay edition from 1910](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/3_purana/visnup_u.htm), the count is **6389**.

Comment: What happened to remaining? Are there any theories about it?

Comment: Someone already asked a question about it: [Is Vishnudharmottara the second part of Vishnu Purana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/35770) I plan to answer it some day. @Govinda